# The easiest way to make a "tracking" item selection in TreeView?

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, qt4, selection

Okay, so I have a `QTreeView` and a Model subclassed from `QAbstractItemModel` set to it. So far so good.

The data of the model gets updated every constant time interval, for example, two seconds. Let's say for simplicity the items are just short integers, and have no hierarchical structure. All items are **unique**.

t=0:

```
497
1739
18
125
19
```

The user selects the item `18`:

t=1:

```
497
1739
[18]
125
19
```

t=2, the list of items updates and changes!

```
497
18
[1739]
125
```

For example, `1739` and `18` are now swapped, and the last `19` disappears.
Whoops! `1739` is now selected, which seems legit: the user has selected the third item, and it's still being selected even after an update.

I hope the question is now obvious: I need the selection to "track" what item exactly is selected. Using some internal id of the item itself. So if the new list contains an item with the same id as the previously selected one, it gets selected.

I could change the selection myself on update, or use `insertRow` and `removeRow`, but I don't know what exactly (`1739` and `18` got swapped) has changed in the list, I just receive a new list of integers.

I've looked at `QItemSelectionModel`, and although the Qt documentation says

> The QItemSelectionModel class keeps track of a view's selected items.

, it doesn't look like what I need. I thought it is another proxy model I need to subclass, but it's not.

Next I thought my Model is the right place to write the code that will track the selection, but I've failed again: a model is unable to retrieve the selection model of the view (`view->selectionModel()`), because it cannot access the view(s).

I could end up writing some signals and slots in my Model so that the code outside the Model could update the selection, plus a slot outside the model connected to the view's selectionModel updating the id of the currently selected item stored in the Model, etc, etc, but before writing such things I thought of asking if there already is some practice I don't know about.

There is so few documentation and articles explaining all these stuff, and I was unable to find an answer to the above myself.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best to detect when items are added/moved/deleted from model and emit respective signals, but this would be to complex and probably you don't need such complex functionality.

Assuming that you are interested in single selection you can do that quite simply. When current selection changes simply store selected value.
When you will be notified that model has changed just find new position of items and update selection.

```
void onCurrentSelectionChange(const QModelIndex & index) { // slot
    selectedValue = index->data(); // update field: QVariant selectedValue
}

void onModelReset() { // slot connected to signal where model reports that it was changed
    QModelIndex newSelection = yourModel->findIndexOfValue(selectedValue); // you have to provide such method in your moel
    emit newSelection(newSelection); // signal connected to setCurrentIndex slot of QTreeView or selection model
}
```

If you want handle more complex selection it will be more trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I think you provide the answer your self.  You can use an internal id that is unique for each item:

```
template<typename T>
class Item {
public:
    Item(int id, T data);
    // Access methods here.
private:
    int id;
    T data;
};
```

Then, every time you receive the `timeout` from your timer you can update your item selection list :

```
vector<int> selection;
for (int &index: treeview->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes()){
    selection.push_back(model[index].id);  // This assumes you implement [] operator for your model.
}

// Do modify list.

// and the using QModelSelection select again every item which id is in 
// `selection`
```

That way you can "track" the selected items.

It is not a good idea depend on the item value, since this limit the solution to a model containing uninque values. Neither is good idea use the `selectionChanged` signal since it will be triggered by the user but also by you when change selections programmatically, and that would generate an infinite loop.

Comment: The question is tagged as "C++".

Comment: Ok, answer translated to C++.